# executing a sql query using python

Tags: python, mysql, select

I'm trying to create a small python app to extract data from specific table of database.
The extracted rows have to be between CREATION_DATETIME specified by user.

Heres the code:

```
startdate = input("Prosze podac poczatek przedzialu czasowego (format RRRR-MM-DD GG:MM:SS): ")
enddate = input("Prosze podac koniec przedzialu czasowego (format RRRR-MM-DD GG:MM:SS): ")
    
query = "SELECT * FROM BRDB.RFX_IKW_MODIFY_EXEC_ORDER_CANCEL_LOG WHERE CREATION_DATETIME between '%s' and '%s' ORDER BY CREATION_DATETIME DESC;"
    
tuple1 = (startdate, enddate)
cursor.execute(*query, (tuple1,))
records = cursor.fetchall()
print("Total number of rows in table: ", cursor.rowcount)
print(records)
```

I'm not much of developer and I'm stuck at error "TypeError: CMySQLCursorPrepared.execute() takes from 2 to 4 positional arguments but 104 were given" in various counts, depends on how I try to modify the code.

Could you guys help me out in specyfing that query correctly?
Thank you in advance.

Tried various tutorial about parametrized query but with no luck.

Comment: try `cursor.execute(query, tuple1)`

Comment: You shouldn't have the `%s` placeholders in quotes, that prevents them from being replaced with the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You're starring the `query`, making it an iterable of the characters making up the string, which probably isn't what you meant (i.e., you should emove the `*` operator). In addition, `tuple1` is already a tuple, you shouldn't enclose it inside another tuple:

```py
cursor.execute(query, tuple1)
# Remove the *-^
# Use tuple1 directly-^
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. Did changes as you advised and the output is this:
Error reading data from MySQL table 1210: Incorrect number of arguments executing prepared statement

+ tried to use cursor.executemany(query, tuple1)
and Im getting

Error reading data from MySQL table 1210: Incorrect type of argument: str(2022-09-13 12:00:00), it must be of type tuple or list the argument given to the prepared statement

Answer (score 0):

here is the full code

```
 import mysql.connector
    from mysql.connector import Error
    
    try:
        print("Laczenie z baza danych....")
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='',
                                             port='',
                                             database='',
                                             user='',
                                             password='')
        if connection.is_connected():
            db_Info = connection.get_server_info()
            print("Wersja servera MySQL:", db_Info)
            cursor = connection.cursor(prepared=True)
            cursor.execute("select database();")
            record = cursor.fetchone()
            print("Pomyslnie polaczono z baza danych: ", record)
            
    except Error as e:
        print("Blad polaczenia!", e)
        quit()
    
    try:
        startdate = input("Prosze podac poczatek przedzialu czasowego (format RRRR-MM-DD GG:MM:SS): ")
        enddate = input("Prosze podac koniec przedzialu czasowego (format RRRR-MM-DD GG:MM:SS): ")
        
        query = "SELECT * FROM BRDB.RFX_IKW_MODIFY_EXEC_ORDER_CANCEL_LOG WHERE CREATION_DATETIME between '%s' and '%s' ORDER BY CREATION_DATETIME DESC;"
        
        tuple1 = (startdate, enddate,)
        cursor.execute(query, tuple1)
        records = cursor.fetchall()
        
        print("Fetching each row using column name")
        for row in records:
            message_id = row["MESSAGE_ID"]
            executable_order_id = row["EXECUTABLE_ORDER_ID"]
            creation_datetime = row["CREATION_DATETIME"]
            message_type = row["MESSAGE_TYPE"]
            message_status = row["MESSAGE_STATUS"]
            print(message_id, executable_order_id, creation_datetime, message_status)
        
    except mysql.connector.Error as e:
        print("Error reading data from MySQL table", e)
    
    
    finally:
        if connection.is_connected():
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
            print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

Comment: This looks like you're providing additional context to your own question, and as such it shouldn't be posted as an answer. Please edit your question and include all the necessary details there instead.